# Save model wrapped in Keras

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow2.0, huggingface-transformers

Sorry for my naive question but I am trying to save my keras model () in which I use TFBertModel() function as an hidden layer. To do that I use the save() function provided by the tf.keras package.

But I got this error:

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

NotImplementedError                       Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-13-3b315f7219da> in <module>()
----> 1 model.save('model_weights.h5')

8 frames

/tensorflow-2.1.0/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/network.py in get_config(self)
    915   def get_config(self):
    916     if not self._is_graph_network:
--> 917       raise NotImplementedError
    918     return copy.deepcopy(get_network_config(self))
    919 

NotImplementedError:
```

The error can be reproduce from my colab : https://colab.research.google.com/drive/18HYwffkXCylPqeA-8raL82vfwOjb-aLP

And another question is how should I call this model for prediction ?

Thx for your help!

Comment: Did you able to solve the problem?

Comment: Hi! yes the lastest version of hugging face transformers includes a saving model function.
https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/2733

Answer (score 0):

Can't really answer you without seeing the code, but you should probably look here:

https://towardsdatascience.com/text-classification-with-hugging-face-transformers-in-tensorflow-2-without-tears-ee50e4f3e7ed